# Setting up Capistrano to deploy to Azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, unicorn, azure-vm-role

I am following [this guide](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/ruby/tutorials/web-app-with-capistrano/), and I am at the step where I attempt to do `cap deploy:cold`. I get the following error:

```
 ** [out :: vm.cloudapp.net] env: /etc/init.d/unicorn_app
 ** [out :: vm.cloudapp.net] : No such file or directory
    command finished in 257ms
failed: "sh -c 'service unicorn_app start'" on vm.cloudapp.net
```

`cap deploy:setup` worked without any errors. That file also exists. Is there any reason why I am unable to start the service? I tried doing `sudo service unicorn_app start`, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The guide provided on the Windows Azure site is  out of date (doesn't fit Capistrano v3) and needs to be updated. I stumbled across this looking for a solution fix the out of date guide, if I find anything I'll post here.